# Splunk lookup and init a token

Tags: lookup, splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have a lookup file , scores.csv

```
ColA,ColB,ColC
Tom,Maths,80
Larry,Science,90
```

Upon page load in splunk, i want to be able to initiate token

```
<set token="user_math_score">{{here i want to be able to set from lookup {{username}} score}} </set>
```

One approach i tried is to see if base search helps this cause

```
<search id="userscores">
<query>
|makeresults |eval ColA="tom"|table ColA|lookup scores ColA AS ColA OUTPUT ColC|eval user_math_score=ColC
</query>
```

but token is not getting populated. Any other better approaches ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the query has run, use a `<condition>` to set the token.

```
<search id="userscores">
  <query>
|makeresults |eval ColA="tom"|table ColA|lookup scores ColA AS ColA OUTPUT ColC|
  </query>
  <done>
    <set token="user_math_score">$results.ColC$</set>
  </done>
</search>
```

Comment: instead of `<condition>`, use `<done>`

Comment: Thanks warren it worked, it should be ```<done>``` , ```<condition>``` wont work, node not supported error will occure when you use condition

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @warren.  I should have put `<change>` before `<condition>`, but `<done>` is better.

Comment: no worries, RichG! We all typo now and then!